# How to use a particular stl version with intel android compiler?

Tags: android, c++11, stl, android-ndk, icc

I'm trying to compile a native Android library using the Intel c++ compiler.

The library compiles without problems using gcc 4.8 (I'm using some c++11 code) but when I set NDK_TOOLCHAIN := x86-icc, it tries to include the stl headers from gcc-4.6

I've read the intel compiler documentation, but I can't find a way to change the include path on the command line. Also setting NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION to 4.8 or specifying a compiler with -gcc-name has no effect.

Is the path hardcoded into the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file `{ndk}/toolchains/x86-icc/setup.mk` and change the variable `GCC_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION` from 4.6 to 4.8.

At least for my small code sample it worked.